# Should base class attribute controlled by Derived class

Tags: java, oop

I am currently working on designing some system where I'm confused if it will be right to control base class attributes with derived class.

For example:

```
Class Building {
   String name;
   String[] facilities;
}

Class OfficeBuilding extends Building{

}

Class ResidentialBuilding extends Building {
}
```

//Type of Building control attribute like facilities here which is empty by default. Should it be part of Derived classes or it should remain part of Base class and derived classes should just override its values ?

Things to keep in mind:
1). All classes are data classes here.
2). Base class facilities attribute is always empty and controlled by child class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one solution. Not knowing your use case I would say name and facilities can be fully managed by parent class, not even directly accessible from child classes (only via constructor / some methods). I would also store facilities as list:

```
Class Building {
   private String name;
   private List<String> facilities;

   public Building(String name, String... facilities) { // facilities won't be null this way
       this.name = name;
       this.facilities = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(facilities));
   }

   public Building(String name) {
       this(name, new String[0]);
   }

   // Only if this makes sense
   public Building() {
       this("");
   }

   public String[] getFacilities() {
       return facilities.toArray(new String[facilities.size()]);
   }

   // if needed you can...
   public void addFacility(String facility) { ... }
   public void removeFacility(String facility) { ... }
}

Class OfficeBuilding extends Building {
    public OfficeBuilding() {
        super("Office", "facility1", "facility2");
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiril. Might i didn't explain my problem well. lets think that you are the client to these classes and there are restrictions put by server on what facilities values could be.

Now as being client, you won't be able to know if you are putting something wrong in these classed without making call to server.

I was thinking is it right thing to do from server perspective or there is better way to deal with it

Comment: @ user3089214: If facilities are set of predefined values, then they should not be a string, but rather define an `Enum Facilities` with all the values you may need, and change implementation to use enum instead of a string.
If you mean certain buildings are only allowed to have certain facilities, then you need something to regulate those rules. Depending on what they are (I'm still unclear) it could be base class, or some other (independent) class that regulates it.

Comment: You are absolutely right about using ENUMs but I don't want to make code changes (adding enums) every time new facilities are added to a category that's the reason I am not making it ENUMs and just strings.

Comment: @user3089214: well, if some part of the program needs to check that facilities are valid, you need to have a list of valid values somewhere, right? You could, for example, store them as an external properties file, database, etc.

Comment: Thanks Kiril, that's what I planned to do. I was bit confused unnesserily but thanks. Discussion was helpful :)